# Is it a good pattern that no objects should know more than what it needs to know?

Tags: programming-practices

I am implementing a controller class to manage a view. I have a file uploader class, Grabber, which could communicate in one of 2 ways:

1) Offer some kind of notification event to the controller on upload start and finish

2) Provide a property on Grabber that indicates true or false if upload has completed

I am concerned that with option 2) I am introducing a dependency between the controller and the Grabber.

What is the better design here?

Comment: It could be a reaction to the phrasing not clearly expressing your question. I'll edit to assist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes it is a good pattern, in fact it is the basis of most patterns and is called [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling)

this will make it easier in general should you need to modify the Grabbing class in the future: for example when you want to notify the viewcontroller of an error that occured during uploading, with the events you define a error event to pass on to the view controller, while otherwise you would need to have a second property that only holds a meaningful value when `grabbing.isDone()` returns true.

also in this case it prevents the busy loop pattern of repeatedly checking the property to see if it changes before moving on

Answer (score 3):

**This appears to be a classic case of the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern**

Therefore, I would suggest that you implement a `GrabEvent` that contains state to indicate if it is a start, finish or error event. The `Grabber` then issues these `GrabberEvent` instances to anyone who has registered as a `GrabberListener` (or `GrabberObserver`).

However, you must make sure that the listeners are decoupled from the event provider (`Grabber`) thread. If not, your `Grabber` event handler will end up calling into the `GrabberListener` instances and updaing their state in a separate thread which could introduce inconsistencies and poor performance if the implementations of those listeners are outside of your control.

In Java, a good way to decouple consumers from providers is to use a `BlockingQueue` so that each end of the queue runs in its own thread.

Comment: Actually it is called [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in GoF Design Patterns. Listener is called `Observer`; and the object where the state is broadcasted from is called `Observable`. Some language frameworks (such as C# and Java) have corresponding classes for this in their class libraries.

Comment: @Spoike Oops. Good call out - will edit accordingly.

Comment: A lot of examples actually call the Observers as Subscribers mostly because it is easier to think in those terms as a metaphor when you implement this pattern. They need to "subscribe" to the data that they want, much like you can subscribe to a newspaper or a magazine.